# How to remove whitespace from a row in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, removing-whitespace

I have a large excel file and I am looking at a single row in it and I want to remove leading and trailing whitespaces from text entries.

My code is as follows:

```
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_name)
layer = df.loc[[layer_index]] # layer is a single row in df and layer_index is an integer
print(layer.iloc[:,37:42])
for col in layer.columns:
    if type(layer[col]) == str:
        layer[col] = layer[col].map(str.strip)
print(layer.iloc[:,37:42])
```

Column 41 contains a lot of leading and trailing whitespace so that the excel entry there is something like      `Cell 3 ramp`          . The output is:

```
   Unnamed: 37 Unnamed: 38 Unnamed: 39                           Unnamed: 40 Unnamed: 41
22         NaN         Ga2         NaN                       Cell 3 ramp             NaN
   Unnamed: 37 Unnamed: 38 Unnamed: 39                           Unnamed: 40 Unnamed: 41
22         NaN         Ga2         NaN                       Cell 3 ramp             NaN
```

But I want it to be such that the whitespaces are removed:

```
   Unnamed: 37 Unnamed: 38 Unnamed: 39                           Unnamed: 40 Unnamed: 41
22         NaN         Ga2         NaN                       Cell 3 ramp             NaN
   Unnamed: 37 Unnamed: 38 Unnamed: 39  Unnamed: 40 Unnamed: 41
22         NaN         Ga2         NaN  Cell 3 ramp         NaN
```

Why doesn't my code work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

we need [minimal and reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a', 'b', '  c'], 'col2':[1, 2, 3], 'col3':['   ab   ', '  bc', 'd']})
```

df

```
col1  col2      col3
0    a     1     ab   
1    b     2        bc
2    c     3         d
```

**Code**

this is code of removing white space from string columns of all.

```
cols = df.select_dtypes('object').columns
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
```

df

```
 col1  col2 col3
0    a     1   ab
1    b     2   bc
2    c     3    d
```

Comment: This answer is not complete as it does not answer the last question "Why doesn't my code work?"

Comment: @DataJanitor Most Pandas respondents would rather provide a possible code than modify and inform the **code that performs the DataFrame with for loop**. First of all, the *code using the for loop is not a recommended code in Pandas.* Therefore, it is not considered an incomplete answer. They all answer like that.